# Getting the sum of each price in a row in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asp.net app where the user can build a vehicle It lists the price of each part but, I want to be able to give them a total cost of each build without saving it back to the database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: do it using JavaScript and calculate the price on the fly and show it to the user

Comment: You have to be much more specific. Please show us some code and what you have allready tried.

Answer (score -1):

At the first i should say that use google for your questions...it is easiest way to get your answer.
but for this questions i think you can use angular and make an minimall app to calculate your building

see this link:
http://www.w3schools.com/angular/